# MySQL creating function and assigning and referencing multiple variables inside function

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a function in MySQL 8.0 where I can assign a variable and then reference that variable for another operation.

I want function to take in a string and cleanse it by:

1. Removing non-alphanumeric values
2. Remove specific substrings
3. Remove some other substrings

Attempted:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION fn_crn_cleanse( name VARCHAR(255) )
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE name_non_alphanumeric VARCHAR(255) ;
    SET name_non_alphanumeric = REGEXP_REPLACE( name , '[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+' , '' ) ;
    
    DECLARE name_remove_suffix VARCHAR(255) ;
    SET name_remove_suffix = REGEXP_REPLACE( name_non_alphanumeric , '\\s(pvt ltd|ltd|limited|llp|plc|partners|inc)$' , '' ) ;
    
    RETURN name_remove_suffix ;

END
;
```

Error I get:

```
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE name_remove_suffix VARCHAR(255) ;
    SET name_remove_suffix = REGEXP_REPLA' at line 9
```

The first step works i.e.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION fn_crn_cleanse( name VARCHAR(255) )
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE name_non_alphanumeric VARCHAR(255) ;
    SET name_non_alphanumeric = REGEXP_REPLACE( name , '[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+' , '' );
    RETURN name_non_alphanumeric ;  
END ;

SELECT fn_crn_cleanse( 'als-k_gh LTD' );
# alskgh LTD
```

but when I try to apply some operation in the function on the variable set inside the function, I get the error. How do I avoid the error and get a working function that cleanses a string input?

Comment: In mysql all declared variables must appear after the begin and before any other code. see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/local-variable-scope.html

Comment: @P.Salmon LEGEND

Comment: I do not see the reason for intermediate variables usage - they're excess. All statements may be combined into one. And after that, the "BEGIN-END" block also becomes redundant.

Comment: @Akina I have a few more variables to add (omitted them to not convolute the question). I would then use this function on different tables' fields. Overkill you reckon?